# Get id as a number in javascript..?

Tags: javascript

A simple question..

```
var x = document.getElementById('xNum');
var y = document.getElementById('xNum');
var result = x * y;

document.write(result);
```

and

```
<div id="xNum">20</div>
<div id="yNum">50</div>
```

It displays 20 and 50. why not calculating 20 * 50? Why does it get as a integer or how can I get numbers in an div?

Thanx!

I don't get any result with that:

```
var x = document.getElementById('xNum').innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById('xNum').innerHTML;
var result = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);

document.write(result);
```

Comment: You can't multiply DOM elements.

Comment: @Jack : sorry, I missed out innerHTML

Comment: You are trying to calculate the elements, rather than the contents of those elements. It's like having a box with 3 buttons in it and another box with 4 buttons in it and trying to calculate "What is box plus box?" (rather than "What is the contents of Box #1 plus the contents of Box #2?").

Comment: @Lucanos Basically what I said ;-)

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, hadn't seen your comment when I committed mine. Nice to know that we were thinking along the same lines, though.

Comment: Additionally ..one typo mistake it should be getElementById instead getByElementId..

Comment: Are `x` and `y` always supposed to be integers or can they be floats too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now the possible ways would have been exhausted, but here's an example with `textContent`:

```
var x = document.getElementById('xNum'),
y = document.getElementById('yNum'),
toIntNum = function(element) {
    return parseInt(element.textContent || element.innerText || 0, 10);
},
result;

result = toIntNum(x) * toIntNum(y);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMSCW/)

Comment: +1 Interesting approach. Probably better to use `element.textContent || element.innerText` than `element.innerHTML`

Comment: I dont wanna be annoying but; if I check your demo it works like charm! however if I copy your code and paste I cant display any result.. is t because of browser or sth?

Comment: I have just pasted same code on my editor to fiddle and on fiddle it works..:S http://jsfiddle.net/hal7/33KeC/

Comment: @user2045937 One thing to make sure is that your JavaScript block is *after* the `<div>`'s

Answer (score 8):

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and process it on their HTML,

```
var result = parseInt(x.innerHTML) * parseInt(y.innerHTML)
```

If you don't need to support browsers priot to IE9, you should use `textContent` instead of innerHTML.

If your numbers might be floats you should check out [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead

If you need to be able to handle numbers like `012` you should specify the radix parameter as they might be interpreted the wrong way by `parseInt`.
 In this case you should use `parseInt(x.innerHTML,10)`

Comment: Don't forget that radix. `parseInt('012') == 10` in Firefox.

Comment: @Blender Thanks, that's a good comment. I don't think that that people write '012' in their numbers. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 5):

it should be

```
var x = document.getElementById('xNum').innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById('yNum').innerHTML;
var result = x * y;

document.write(result);
```

Comment: I agree with Pranav, and  casting required if using float value :)

Comment: I'd just like to say that this type of implicit casting bit me in the ass before. I think that the fact the language allows us to do  `"20" * "50"` or `"20" % "7"` because some vendor (no naming) insisted is a mistake in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

Parse them into integers:

```
var x = document.getElementById('xNum');
var y = document.getElementById('yNum');

var result = parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) * parseInt(y.innerHTML, 10);
```

Comment: one typo mistake it should be getElementById instead getByElementId

Comment: @Pranav: Yep, it should. Thanks

Comment: and if I say document.write(result); I dont get any result..?

Answer (score 2):

The value you are getting is a string, so in order to use it as a number you should cast it to the integer (or float):

```
var x = +document.getElementById('xNum').innerHTML;
var y = +document.getElementById('xNum').innerHTML;
var result = x * y;
```

I used unary `+` operator, there are another methods like `parseInt`, `Number` constructor, etc.

Comment: on typo mistake it should be getElementById instead getByElementId

Answer (score 0):

Js:

```
var x = document.getByElementId('xNum').innerHTML;
var y = document.getByElementId('xNum').innerHTML;
var result = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);

document.write(result);
```

Comment: Correction : var y = document.getElementById('yNum'); , then only we will get the value of that div as 50.

Answer (score 0):

you must cast as int so calculation done. By default the value consider as string .

```
  var x = document.getByElementId('xNum');
var y = document.getByElementId('xNum');
var result = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);  //use parseInt or parseDouble 

document.write(result);
```

and

`<div id="xNum">20</div>
<div id="yNum">50</div>`

it give 1000

Comment: As user Jack rightfully pointed it out, this will not work , because you are accessing the DOM element and not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseInt()` function in javascript for parsing a string to return an integer.

Your code should be like this :

```
   var x = document.getElementById('xNum');
   var y = document.getElementById('yNum');
   var result = parseInt(x.innerHTML) * parseInt(y.innerHTML); 

   document.write(result);
```